# CSS vertical align

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have a img in floated div and I don't know how to center it vertically.

```
<div style="height: 300px">
   <img style="height: 50px" src="something" />
</div>
```

vertical-align: middle of course doesn't work.

http://jsfiddle.net/wKQYj/

Comment: The two ways this article mentions have been given already as separate answers but you would be a better CSSer if you knew the what `vertical-align` was actually used for: http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/

Comment: @scragz - That is a good link. Though, I wouldn't use `display:table-cell`. Of course, I wouldn't use my proposed answer of `<table>` either. Ha.

Comment: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/B2mW8NiCQAA6IIP.jpg

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I vertically align text in a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939914/how-do-i-vertically-align-text-in-a-div)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To vertically-align text within a parent element, and bear in mind that an `img` is an inline-element and so behaves **similarly** to text, you can simply set the `line-height` to the `height` of the parent element:

```
div {
    height: 300px;
    line-height: 300px;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/xQ4mn/).

Answer (score 13):

The `vertical-align` CSS style specifies the alignment of text within its text row. This allows you to specify text as superscript or subscript, for example.

So it isn't actually intended to vertically align an element within a box.

There is an explicit exception to this, however -- table cells (ie `<td>` and `<th>` elements) use the `vertical-align` style to do exactly that: align the contents of the cell within the cell.

This exception is something of a quirk - it really shouldn't exist. The CSS designers put it in there in order to allow CSS to reproduce the `valign` attribute of table elements, which was commonly used by designers in the dark-old days of table-based layouts.

For other elements, aligning the contents of a box vertically in the middle of the it can be a bit of a fine art. There are several techniques:

1. For single lines of text, simply make the `line-height` the same as the height of the entire box. You probably won't even need `vertical-align` for this.
2. Use `display:table-cell;` to make the element simulate a table cell, and then use `vertical-align`. This works, but may have unintended consequences (there are other attributes of table cells that you may not want to simulate).
3. If you know the height of the element you want to vertically align, you can position it to 50% minus half its height, like this:

   ```
   position:absolute;
   top:50%;
   height:200px;
   margin-top:-100px; /* half the height */
   ```

There are a few others, but these should get you started.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 5):

For a more modern (IE8+) solution that doesn't use tables, I like [this one](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/) best.

```
<style>
/* Can be any width and height */
.block {
  height:500px;
  text-align: center;
}

/* The ghost, nudged to maintain perfect centering */
.block:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: -0.25em; /* Adjusts for spacing */
}

/* The element to be centered, can be any width or height */ 
.centered {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 300px;
}
</style>

<div class="block"><div class="centered">Centered Content</div></div>
```

Comment: Best solution indeed, since it does not need to know the height of the content and does not use table-cell css. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: is there a way to do this while having .centered be a percent width (that might actually be 100%).

Answer (score 5):

Use the translate property, it's simple and works even in IE:

```
img {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`vertical-align` property is only truly good on `td` elements. Try something like:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td style='height:300px; vertical-align:center'>
   <img src='something'>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

OR since you know the height and width of the `img`:

```
<div style='height:300px;'>
 <img style='height:50px; position:relative; top:50%; margin-top:-25px'>
</div>
```

Comment: ZOMG, none of the above seems ok to me, I mean there's serious hole in css, they're developing shadows etc and we have to use tables still or at divs in divs to center vertically... Holy cow. I have to use divs. And I can't use the second code because the div height will be changed by users. So I'm lost.

Comment: @anonymous: are you able to use JavaScript, or any JS libraries (MooTools, Scriptaculous, jQuery, Glow...)?

Answer (score 2):

Pretty [cool and modern approach](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/) (with height specified):

```
.Absolute-Center {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the display:box property:

```
#container {
    display: box;
    box-orient: vertical;
    box-pack: center;  
}

#text {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

See the js-fiddle here: [verical align js-fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p3m85fgw/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Javascript would probably be the best best to get the image centered in the vertical center for every case. if you can use a library like jQuery it's just a few lines of code.

```
$(function(){
    var containerHeight = $('#container').outerHeight();
    var imgHeight = $('#logo img').outerHeight();

    var difference = (containerHeight - imgHeight)/2;
    $('#logo img').css({'position' : 'relative', 'top' : difference + 'px'});
```

});

Comment: So he needs to include the full jQuery library, plus this script? Seems a little overkill just to center something.

Comment: if he has to center something more than a few times and if he doesn't know A) what the height of the parent div is, and B) what the height of the image is, this will work every time, and in every case

Answer (score 1):

I'm using flex for centering an element. It is effective at making the page more responsive.

```
div {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Please have a look [here](https://vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/) to learn how to center vertically.