# Vertically aligning multiple lines of text in IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I am trying to vertically align text in IE7 is proving to be a PITA without the css options of `display: table;` and `display: table-cell;`

It is for a navigation that looks similar to this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Text covers one line</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Text covers two lines, problem occurs</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul li a{ display: table; zoom: 1; width: 240px; height: 30px;}
ul li a span{ width: 200px; display: table-cell; zoom: 1; vertical-align: middle; padding: 0 30px 0 20px; }
```

Works on newer browsers. I can get the text to center easily with only one line of text, but when it goes to two I can't seem to get anything working.

Comment: You realise your spans aren't properly closed?

Comment: If closing the span properly doesn't fix it would you mind using JavaScript? That's the only way I can think of without some hacky CSS classes on each <li> and some backend  logic to count letters.

Comment: This question may help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785871/css-vertical-align

Comment: Sorry the span was just a typo, it isn't broken in my markup. The question you posted works for a single line of text (setting the line-height to the same height of the div), but you can imagine the results when there are two lines of text...

Comment: Also in response to JS, I guess I wouldn't mind using that. I'd prefer it over a huge excess of markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know there is a lot of table-hate around here (and much is clearly justified). But you *must support IE7* as a requirement - clearly we're not going to be using the latest technology here.

So, if you can't get it to work with the limited set of CSS, why not just *actually use a table?* If you must support a browser from [2006](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_7) there will be compromises. As much as it hurts me to say this: Sometimes you've got to take a deep-breath, throw a standard out the window, and think to yourself, "If it works, it works."

Comment: Yea it sucks, thanks for the response, it may be the only non-js solution.

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions I am aware of, but each has its small discomfort. Please look at **[this demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/jLtmV/2/)** showing both.

The first solution is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206640/css-vertically-align-div-when-no-fixed-size-of-the-div-is-known/7277724#7277724) which has the downside that the clickable area is compressed to only the text, and does not extend to the list item bounds. I suppose this is not be a great problem, since users will likely click the text rather then next to it.

The second solution is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206640/css-vertically-align-div-when-no-fixed-size-of-the-div-is-known/7256012#7256012) which has the downside that you need one extra element in the markup. I chose for an `<ins>` tag, but you can use any other inline element.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your task correctly, there is absolutely no need in using tables. The main reason for that is that if you have a number of `li` elements that exceeds the width of your page, you will definitely have problems with making them wrap nicely.

So, is that what you are trying to achieve?

http://jsfiddle.net/EK357/

The solution is based on: http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/

To cut it short, you have to set these rules for each `li` element:

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
    display: -moz-inline-box; /* Firefox < 3.5 */
    *display: inline; /* IE */
    zoom: 1;

    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: -.3em;
}
```

Be aware, though, that there is an extra whitespace after each `inline-block` element (that's what `margin-left: -.3em` for.