# Vertical align of inline HTML elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I know there is tons of questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79461/vertical-alignment-of-elements-in-a-div),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489340/how-do-i-vertically-align-text-next-to-an-image-with-css),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785871/css-vertical-align),[4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939914/vertically-align-text-in-a-div),[5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527811/css-vertical-centering)) about inline elements I couldn't make it.

In Twitter Bootstrap I have an alert row, but the bell icon in right side isn't vertically aligned with the text in left side. Icon appears lower than the text. I tried `vertical-align:middle;` `.row` `line-height` etc. I also need the solution be responsive in mobile screens.

You can see my tryouts in fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mavent/DdLED/37/

```
<div class="alert alert-warning ">Today many things happened <span class="badge badge-info">121</span>
    <div class="pull-right"><a class="btn btn-lg" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myTable"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Edit: Solution:**
I solved issue like the example 8 in fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mavent/DdLED/45/

Comment: Try display:inline-block; with the vertical align.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you? (I know, a bit of a hack)

[ CSS ]

```
.bring_it_up {
    margin-top: -3px;
}
```

[ HTML ]

```
<!-- part 8 -->
<div class="alert alert-warning border2 "><span class="border">Today many things happened Part 8</span><span class="border  badge badge-info">121</span>
 <a class="bring_it_up no_padding pull-right btn btn-lg" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myTable"><i class="no_padding glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></i>
</a>
</div>
```