# How to show a text at the middle of the age and the image at the left side of the page

Tags: html, css

I have the following markup

```
<img  style="float: left;" src="c:\1.png"> <h1 style="float: center;">ttt</h1>
```

which i got this result:-

[image]

but i need the `h1` to be at the middle of the page and also horizontally align at the middle of the picture,, can anyone advice ?
Thanks

Comment: vertical alignment in html/css is a massive pile of stinking fecal matter.  your best bet is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785871/css-vertical-align followed by a late night visit to the W3C members who decided that vertical alignment wasn't wanted/needed, and leaving some of that fecal matter on their front steps in flaming paper bags

Comment: you mean vertically align at the middle of the picture? btw, `float:center` doesn't exist

Comment: but what if the image's width extends beyond the middle of the page?

Answer (score 0):

there is no `float: center;` in CSS. Instead you should use `text-align: center;` or `margin: 0px auto;`. Also I recommend to you to use a CSS file or atleast seperate the code in the document, so you can tidy up your html code and make it easier to maintain. To horizontally align you can use `vertical-align: middle`: [Link to a sample](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/). or give it a `margin-top: 50%;`

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JrhQh/289/)

```css
div {
    display: table;
}
h1 {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align:center;
}

img{
 width:150px;
 height:150px;
 background:red
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="c:\1.png" /> <h1>ttt</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: but this will not move the H1 to be at the center of the page is this correct ?  and the H1 will be near the image...

Comment: You want the picture to be at the middle of the page too? or just the h1 like this? http://jsfiddle.net/JrhQh/290/

Comment: no to keep the image at left side, but move the text to the middle??

Comment: like this?   http://jsfiddle.net/JrhQh/292/ or like this http://jsfiddle.net/JrhQh/291/