# Center a button horizontally and vertically in a div

Tags: html, css

I would like to **center** a **button horizontally** and **verticaly** in a middle of a `div` for my project.

Here is the html code:

```
<div class="PageHeader_wrapper" id="header-buttons">
  <form id="CreateAccount" action="CreateAccount.php" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Create an account">
  </form>
</div>
```

and the **CSS** here :

```
#header-buttons {
  margin-right: 35px;
  float: right;
  height: 68px;
  width: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Js fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/m635r2rf/10/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/m635r2rf/11/ You can do that like that, but you need to set a width for a parent

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS vertical align](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785871/css-vertical-align)

Comment: You need to search SO for the already too many solutions to this same question.

Answer (score 6):

Use a combination of `display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;`. Also, this is a useful reference https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html

```css
#header-buttons {
  margin-right: 35px;
  float: right;
  height: 68px;
  width: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="PageHeader_wrapper" id="header-buttons">
  <form id="CreateAccount" action="CreateAccount.php" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Create an account">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Very nice ! it does the job ! Thanks for the quick answer. ^_^

Answer (score 5):

A simple solution is to use flexbox: Add these settings to your wrapper:

```
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3t7ynn6p/

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is to set a `line-height` on the form element:

```
#CreateAccount {
  line-height: 60px;
}
```

This is 60px in this situation because your parent element is 68px, and the default font-size is 16px. Half of the font-size of the button should equal the difference from the parent's line-height.

Essentially, it would be:

```
#CreateAccount {
  line-height: calc(100% - (1em /2)); /* calc([parent height] - ([font-size] / 2)); */
}
```

I've created a fiddle showcasing this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/064cr178/).

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you ! it helped me out ^_*

Answer (score 0):

You can use table for that (probably easiest and most backward-compatible method).

```
#header-buttons {
    margin-right: 35px;
    float: right;
    height: 68px;
    width: auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: table;
}

#CreateAccount {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

for horizontal alignment just use `text-align` property (as button is `inline-block`) as in example here: 
https://jsfiddle.net/m635r2rf/64/

Answer (score 0):

**HTML code change**:  added one id for button to select.

```
 <div class="PageHeader_wrapper" id="header-buttons">
              <form id="CreateAccount" action="CreateAccount.php" method="post">
                <input type="submit" id="createBtn" value="Create an account">
      </form>
```

**CSS code change:** removed styling from div and added in the button as below -

```
 #createBtn {
   position: fixed;
   left: 50%;
   top:50%;
 }
```